# How do I access a parameter's description in AWS parameter store, using boto3 in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to pull a description from a parameter I have created in AWS parameter store. I can write the description as seen in this code below:

```
    import boto3
    import json
    from datetime import date, datetime

    def json_datetime_serializer(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
            return obj.isoformat()
        raise TypeError("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))
    AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"

    ssm_client = boto3.client("ssm", region_name=AWS_REGION)

    new_pass=input("Would you like to create a new password? ")
    while True:
        if new_pass == "yes":
            new_list_parameter = ssm_client.put_parameter(
                Name = input ("Enter service: "), 
                Description = input ("Enter username:"), #this is what I would like to access and assign to a variable as a string
                Value= "epass",
                Type='SecureString',
                Overwrite=True,
                Tier='Standard',
                DataType='text'
            )
            print("Done!")
            break
        else:
            break
```

BUT, when I try to access that parameter, I cannot seem to assign the description to a string. I can only access the value. I have looked for days, any help?

```
    while True:
        read_info=input("Service: ") #Ask for service
        read_info=read_info.upper()
        get_pw = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name=read_info,
               WithDecryption=True)
        get_username = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name=read_info,
              WithDecryption=True)
        str_encrypted_pw = get_pw['Parameter']['Value']
        str_username = get_username['Parameter']['Description']
        print("Username:\n ",str_username)
        print("Password:")
        print(str(decrypted_pw,'utf8'))
        break
```

Comment: Your code is not even a valid python code. Please make sure that your code is **reproducible**.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my code with more information so it is reproducible.

Comment: " I try to access that parameter" where do you access the parameter? your code only shows `put`, not `get` of the parameter.

Comment: @Marcin I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_parameter()` function returns:

```json
{
    'Parameter': {
        'Name': 'string',
        'Type': 'String'|'StringList'|'SecureString',
        'Value': 'string',
        'Version': 123,
        'Selector': 'string',
        'SourceResult': 'string',
        'LastModifiedDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'ARN': 'string',
        'DataType': 'string'
    }
}
```

There is no `Description` field in the information returned.

However, I happen to notice that [`get_parameter_history()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter) *does* return a `Description`, so you could likely retrieve it that way.

If it is information that you always wish to retrieve, then you could store it in the parameter value itself (eg as a JSON dictionary), or store it in a second parameter with a similar name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Storing the value in a JSON dictionary is way more practical than using the description. Thanks!